# Creating Different mobile layout for a component in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, mobile, layout, react-redux

How can we create a completely different (mobile type layout) for a component (having a different desktop type layout) using ReactJs.
(Not Responsive , responsive is something css has to take care of.)
It should be different layout for the component  i.e here Creating a page with a menu(header menu) for desktop screens which becomes a navigation sidebar with logo on small screen.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Honestly, a simple resposive css layout may be the best solution, but the steps are to

1) Detect in JS if user in on mobile or desktop. For example this question has a good suggestion as an answer: [Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)

2) Use it to decide in your root component that which layout to use:

```
function isMobile() {
  // some js way to detect if user is on a mobile device
}

class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    return isMobile() ? ( <MobileLayout /> ) : ( <DesktopLayout /> )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Checkout [react-responsive](https://github.com/contra/react-responsive), You can use media query to render different component depending on device size.